# Excel VBA: Selecting Chart data from dynamic sheet

Tags: excel, vba, graph, charts

I am trying to create a program that will load multiple data sets into their own sheet, then create a chart based off the data. I have been struggling with getting the proper data for the chart. I have been using a counter to label my data sets as they are put onto a sheet.
My sheet name has been defined as a string like below. The program gets an error when it attempts to get the data..

```
Dim CurrentSheet is string
CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Charts.Add
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=CurrentSheet!$C$2:$C$100000"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=CurrentSheet!$A$2:$A$100000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim CurrentSheet As String

CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & CurrentSheet & "!$C$2:$C$100000"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & CurrentSheet & "!$A$2:$A$100000"
```

*Later edit*

Even better, to deal with the cases when the Sheet name has white chars inside:

```
Dim CurrentSheet As String

CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & CurrentSheet & "'!$C$2:$C$100000"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & CurrentSheet & "'!$A$2:$A$100000"
```